# html selectbox Required error

Tags: javascript, forms

I have one form with some fields, with text fields regular html5 validations works nice, but when I have selectboxes I get this error on javascript console:

> An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable

Anyone had this problem too?

Comment: Post the code you are having this trouble with.

Comment: Preferable with an [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I problem is that I have an condition (true or false) to show or an inputbox or an selectbox but I use angularjs ng-show and I need to use ng-if so that hidden field dont throw validation error

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found the problem